# Как создать HWID на php?

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет, у меня есть проблема. 2 месяца назад я сделал сайт где есть личный кабинет, чат и ещё много чего. И не давно я узнал о такой вещи как «HWID». У меня был вопрос, как можно его сделать на php то есть в личном кабинете будет кнопка или ссылка на сброс HWID. И вообще можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А зачем Вам HWID?

Comment: Чтобы нельзя было зайти в аккаунт с другого устройства

Comment: А если человер решит зайти с телефона находясь в метро, а потом дома решит зайти? Сомнительное решение

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно, чтобы пользователь, вошедший в свой аккаунт с одного устройства, автоматически завершал свой сеанс на другом, храните в таблице пользователей какое-нибудь поле `access_token`. При авторизации пользователя генерируйте его заново, сохраняйте в БД пользователю и отправляйте его в куки/сессию